# How do I avoid nil class in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, null

I get the following error, and *thought* by using the .nil? method I could avoid getting an error by identifying the exception.  But I don't.

Line 40 shows I am getting an error...it seems to think that contact.latest_event is nil.  But shouldn't .nil? help me avoid getting the error?  Thanks...!

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass) on line #40
of app/views/companies/show.html.erb:
37:     <p>
38:             <%= full_name(contact) %>, <%= contact.status %><%= contact.titl
e %>,
39:             <span class='date_added'>added <%= contact.date_entered %>
40:                     <% if !contact.latest_event.nil?%>
41:                       last event: <%= contact.latest_event.date_sent %>
42:                     <% end %>
43:             </span>
```

**Here is latest_event:**

```
 def latest_event
   [contact_emails, contact_calls, contact_letters].map do |assoc|
          assoc.first(:order => 'date_sent DESC')
      end.compact.sort_by { |e| e.date_sent }.last
 end
```

I guess it's possible none of the Models contact_emails, for example, have been done...but what do I do if there aren't any that exist?

Comment: Could you please post the code from your `latest_event` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can solve your problem changing the `latest_event` method.

```
def latest_event
   events = [contact_emails, contact_calls, contact_letters].map do |assoc|
          assoc.first(:order => 'date_sent DESC')
      end.compact

   events.sort_by{ |e| e.date_sent }.last unless events.blank?
end
```

And just a comment: when you need `if`s like this

```
if !contact.latest_event.nil?
```

it's better to use `unless`:

```
unless contact.latest_event.nil?
```

Comment: cool trying it out now...I actually had unless statement, but it was erroring out so thought I was using it wrong.  So will put it back as you said, thanks, checking it out now!

Comment: oh crap -- still getting the same error....why is it doing the <=> even though I don't use it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `latest_event` does, but it seems like your nil is actually in `latest_event` since it's doing a comparison (`<=>`). What does `latest_event` look like?

Answer (score 0):

The method <=> is used to implement basic operators as <, >, =>, ... (see the [module Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html)). But I can't see where you use them, actually ... it may be inside the latest_event method.

Asides, the following statements are equivalent:

```
if !contact.latest_event.nil?
unless contact.latest_event.nil?
if contact.latest_event   # Only nil and false evaluate as false
```

Comment: I find the last of those 3 to be the nicest :)

Answer (score 0):

You're implicitly using `<=>` when you use `sort_by`.

Here's one possible workaround, assuming that `date_sent` holds a `Date` object:

```
def latest_event
  [contact_emails, contact_calls, contact_letters].map do |assoc|
    assoc.first(:order => 'date_sent DESC')
  end.compact.sort_by { |e| e.date_sent.nil? ? Date.new : e.date_sent }.last
end
```

Your problem is that some of your records have a `null` in the `date_sent` column. When you ask ruby to sort by this value, ruby doesn't know how to compare `nil` with a `Date`. To do the sorting comparisons, ruby uses `<=>` (see the docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) on what this operator does).

In the code above, I added logic to substitute a placeholder `Date` when `date_sent` is `nil`. That placeholder is Jan 1, -4712 (a very old date). That means records with `date_sent == nil` will be placed first in the sort result.

If your `date_sent` is a `Time`, then you can use `Time.at(0)` instead of `Date.new`.